# Могу ли я организовать вычислительный кластер на основе MS Server 2012 R2?

Tags: сервер, сеть, кластер, windows-server-2012

Имеется 1 сервер, с установленной ос MS Server 2012 R2, а также пару простых рабочих станций с ос Windows 7. Все это объеденено в локальную сеть.

Могу ли я организовать вычислительный кластер? Если да, оставьте пожалуйста ссылки на какие-нибудь туториалы или вспомогательные материалы.

Comment: Гугл

    openmpi windows cluster HPC

и подобные запросы выводят на кучу статей.

Comment: все что находил, это как организовать кластер на основе 2х и больше серверов, с установлеными на них MS Server 2012 R2

на тему организации кластера на основе одного сервера и рабочих станций ничего найти не удалось

Comment: @iceone23, неужели сервер от станции в винде так сильно отличаются, что openmpi не будет работать?

Тогда переходите на \*nix.

Comment: @avp, оставьте пожалуйста ссылки на какие-нибудь туториалы или вспомогательные материалы, таковых я не нашел

Comment: @iceone23, только что набрал в гугле

    openmpi windows cluster

получил 

    Результатов: примерно 90 700

IMHO у Вас тоже должно получиться.

Comment: @avp, дайте хоть одну ссылку, которая ответи на мой вопрос